# Angluarjs: How to display image having the javax.ws.rs.core response object?

Tags: angularjs, image, base64

Here is my server side code:

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}/photo")
@Produces(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response getPhoto(@PathParam("id") Long id){

    String imgData = //raw content of file 
    return Response
            .ok(imgData, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .header("content-disposition", "attachment; filename = testDownloadImage.png")
            .build();
}
```

I want to display the image on browser. The Resource on client is:

```
return $resource('', null, {
       getPhoto: {
            method: 'GET',
            url:  baseURL + ':id/photo',
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
            isArray: false
        }
})
```

And

```
resoucre.getPhoto({id: ID}).$promise
                .then(function (returnedPhoto) {
                    if (returnedPhoto != null) {
                        $scope.photo = returnedPhoto;
                    }
                });
```

And HTMl is

```
      <img ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{photo}}"/><br/>
```

But the image is not shown and I have some weird data like here

```
GET data:image/png;base64,{"0":"i","1":"V","2":"B"...
```